# how to convert class type to string selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
web = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\gohar\PycharmProjects\Parctice\webs\chromedriver.exe")
web.get('https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/?ref_=nv_mv_250')
rating = web.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@class="ratingColumn imdbRating"]')
moviename = web.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@class="titleColumn"]')
numrating = len(rating)
for i in range(numrating):
    print(rating[i].text + ' : ' + moviename[i].text)
    web.close()
```

How do I manage the print I got? So I can pull out the movie with 8 rating for example

Comment: what is the current print statement printing?

Comment: that's printed all the movies and their rating

Comment: isn't that what you want

Comment: i want to know how i take the 8 stars rating movies  for example

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question needs some work so the community can better help you. Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give it another try.

Answer (score 0):

You can find below solution to print specific rating list of movies :

```
from selenium import webdriver
web = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\New folder\chromedriver.exe")
web.get('https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/?ref_=nv_mv_250')
rating = web.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@class="ratingColumn imdbRating"]')
moviename = web.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@class="titleColumn"]')
numrating = len(rating)
for i in range(numrating):
    if rating[i].text == "9.0":
      print(rating[i].text + ' : ' + moviename[i].text)
web.close()
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Updated solution with float**

```
web.get('https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/?ref_=nv_mv_250')
rating = web.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@class="ratingColumn imdbRating"]')
moviename = web.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@class="titleColumn"]')
numrating = len(rating)

for i in range(numrating):
    if (float(rating[i].text) )==float(8.2):
      print(rating[i].text + ' : ' + moviename[i].text)
web.close()
```

Comment: ok , thanks !
but if i want that the rating[i].text will be equal to a float input like customer_selection = float(input('How IMDb Rating movie do you want? ')) it's not receive any output , why?

Comment: please check Updated solution with float and once you verify then would you kind enough to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) answer and hit upvote button from your end.